# Getting error while installing GoogleAds-IMA-iOS-SDK (~> 3.14.5)

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, google-ima

Iam getting this error while installing pods from the terminal. It seems like version 3.14.5 is not ready for user
With version 3.14.4 its working fine. I have tried pod repo update, pod update all the things
Is 3.14.5 is the beta version?

[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "GoogleAds-IMA-iOS-SDK":
In Podfile:
GoogleAds-IMA-iOS-SDK (~> 3.14.5)

None of your spec sources contain a spec satisfying the dependency: `GoogleAds-IMA-iOS-SDK (~> 3.14.5)`.

You have either:

- mistyped the name or version.
- not added the source repo that hosts the Podspec to your Podfile.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://cocoapods.org/pods/GoogleAds-IMA-iOS-SDK, the latest published version to CocoaPods is 3.14.4

[image]